# Placeholder for xml views that only apply to the design preview tab in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

In Android Studio, I'd love to be able to preview my view in the design tab.
However, since the many get initialised not before runtime, the preview looks poorly empty. There are textviews and images that appear white because  no string resource or image resource has been set yet. 
Setting the resources in xml is bad style and inflexible. I wish there was a way so that I can show placeholders that only apply in the Android Studio design preview tab. It should be possible to express something like

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        preview:text="lorem ipsum"
/>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        preview:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder"
/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct prefix is `tools`.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="lorem ipsum" />
```

They even have samples you can use within the tools. Such as `tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem"`

For a full list of all the attributes supported, check out the docs. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes

Answer (score 1):

you were pretty close:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:src="drawable/ic_placeholder"
/>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools
>   namespace that enable design-time features (such as which layout to
>   show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking
>   mode to apply to your XML resources). **When you build your app, the
>   build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK
>   size or runtime behavior.**

You can use `tools:text="Hello World!"`attribute as follows

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Hello World!"/>
```

and/or Blueprint view as follows:

[image: blueprintview]

Answer (score 0):

for ImageView you can Use like this

```
  tools:srcCompat ="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic"
```